# Is there a functional reason for the naming convention for custom actions?

Tags: custom-component, acl

I'm writing a component for which I'd like to implement some additional restrictions on actions. For example, I want administrators to be able to view user details, but restrict some sensitive information to a specific group of administrators. For this special right, I've defined an additional action `core.view.sensitive`:

```
<action name="core.admin" title="..." description="..." /> 
<action name="core.view" title="..." description="..." /> 
<action name="core.view.sensitive" title="..." description="..." />
```

I'm trying to follow conventions here, but what is the purpose of the dot-notation for the action names? Is there some implicit hierarchy I'm not aware of? Do all users with the right to action `core.view`, automatically also get `core.view.sensitive` (or vice versa)? Of is it all just for aesthetics?

Comment: Please take our [tour] while you wait for support/feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it currently makes no difference in terms of code. So it is only a human readable way of indicating hierarchy. Be aware that you can't use whitespaces and hyphens in action names because these are stripped out by Access library.

Comment: I've tried to figure out how rights are being saved and edited and I think that you're right. So there is no correlation between the dot-notation and any form or hierarchy. Thanks